# How to loop through checkedlistbox and remove selected items in c#

Tags: c#, loops, checkedlistbox

In my app users can add some item in `checkedlistbox`, then user selects some element and clicks the button **"Remove"**. How can I loop through my `checkedListBox` and remove selected items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the count of checked items and remove on while loop as below

```
while (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0) {
   checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[0]);
}
```

OR

```
int lastIndex =checkedListBox1.Items.Count-1;
for(int i=lastIndex ; i>=0 ; i--)
{
    if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
    {
             checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to loop through checkedlistbox and check, if item selected - remove it?

Comment: if you going to loop and remove don't use `foreach` it will not work, and also you can use for loop but remove items from last to first.

Comment: Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: THANK YOU! I spend 3 hours on it! A lot of strange with checkedListBox! ... But put semicolons instead of comas in for statement. It's c# Maybe someone will use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it. It is working code

```
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
    {
         CheckBoxList1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
         i--;
     }
}
```

Comment: Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If two selected items are one after another, you'll skip the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to removing certain elements from a list of those elements is to walk the list in reverse - from count-1 to 0.  That way when you remove an element, the indexes of remaining ones you still care about have not changed.